# Equivalent tensorflow.js function for tf.compat.v1.image.resize?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I want to replicate the functionality of `tf.compat.v1.image.resize(inputs, [height, width], align_corners=True)` using tensorflow.js. What function or combination of functions in tensorflow.js would give the equivalent result as the above function?

Answer (score 0):

There is `tf.image.resizeBilinear` (respectively `tf.image.resizeNearestNeighbor`) which will performs a resize using the bilinear sampling (respectively the nearest neighbor sampling)